# $\mathbb{R}[x]/\langle x-5\rangle \cong $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm a bit stuck on this one.

> Thought about defining $\phi:\mathbb{R}[x]\rightarrow\mathbb{R} $
>
> as $\phi(p(x))=p(5)$.  So we can see that $\ker\phi=\langle x-5\rangle$

How could I proceed from here?

Answer (score 3):

I presume you're trying to identify $\mathbb R[x]/(x-5)$?

$\phi$ is a homomorphism of rings. As you mentioned, ${\rm ker} \phi = (x-5)$. It shouldn't be hard to see that ${\rm im} \phi = \mathbb R$. Now use the fact that if $\phi : R \to S$ is a ring homomorphism, then $R/{\rm ker } \phi \cong {\rm im} \phi$.

Comment: Identifying $Im\phi = \mathbb{R}$ was my problem. How did you get that?

Comment: If I give you a number $c \in \mathbb R$, can you find a polynomial $\phi(x) \in \mathbb R[x]$ such that $\phi(5) = c$?

Comment: How about the constant polynomial, $\phi(x) = c$?

Comment: Right... thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Let $q(x)$ be an element in $\Bbb R[x]$, and let $n=\deg q(x)$. Then
$$q(x)=(x-5)g(x)+r(x),$$ but $r(x)\in \Bbb R$, so it is a constant because $\deg g(x)=n-1$.

Thus $\Bbb R[x]/( x-5 ) \cong \Bbb R$, because $\ker\phi=\{p(x) : (x-5)/ p(x)\}\cong \Bbb R_{\ge 1}[x]$.

EDIT: the last isomorphism is the following. First of all choose $\mathcal{B}=\{1,x-5,x^2-25,\dots,x^n-5^n\dots\}$ as basis for $\Bbb R[x]$ and $\ker\phi=\langle \mathcal{B}\setminus \{1\}\rangle$. Then the isomorphism is given by a map sending $x^n-5^n$ to $x^n$.

Comment: Why a downvote?

Comment: It might be because assuming the $\phi$ is the same as in the question you have described the kernel incorrectly.

Comment: The kernel is still incorrect after your edit. For instance $\phi(x) = 5$, while $deg(x) \geq 1$.

Comment: What is the final isomorphism supposed to be? Did you forget to edit it out?

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb{R}_{ \geq 1}[X]$ ? I would read that as polynomials with real coefficients all greater than $1$. Then your isomorphism is false, since $-(x-5) \mapsto -x$ which is not in $\mathbb{R}_{ \geq 1}[X]$. Did you mean to say $\mathbb{R}[X]_{\geq 1}$, i.e. all polynomials of degree greater than $0$? In that case, why are you including that isomorphism? All you are saying is that $ker \phi$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Clearly $\Bbb R[x]_{\ge1}$ include polynomial of degree $1$ and greater than one. I include this isomorphism because you asked me this.

Comment: Yes, I asked you to explain the isomorphism that you initially wrote. However, I don't see why the isomorphism has anything to do with the answer in the first place. To me it seems like you are implying that $\Bbb R[X]/(ker \phi) \cong \Bbb R$ because $ker(\phi) \cong \mathbb{R}[X]_{ \geq 1}$, but this is not what is going on at all.